# Create JSON string in iOS

Tags: ios, json, web-services, http-post

How to create JSON string for HTTP Request in iOS

i have these values:

```
{"name":"customer6","pass":"customer6",  "mail":"customer6@xy.com","user_roles":"5", "field_login_pin_value":{"und":[{"value":"2324"}]} }
```

So how to make JSON string out of this data ?

Here is my code :

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name",@"pass",@"mail",@"user_roles",@"field_login_pin_value", nil];

NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"customer6",@"customer6",@"customer6@xy.com",@"5",@"{\"und\":[{\"value\":\"2324\"}]", nil];

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSString *jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];


NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxx/register.json"]];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"json"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

nsconnection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

When I hit the web-service request, I get the following response:

```
 "form_errors" =     {
        "field_login_pin_value][und][0][value" = "PIN value field is required.";
    };
}
```

I always get the same error

Can anyone let me know what is wrong with my implementation ?

Comment: You've only partly constructed the JSON.  The string `,@"{\"und\":[{\"value\":\"2324\"}]"` almost certainly should be encoded as JSON, not a character string.  Refer to json.org to understand the JSON syntax -- what you want to create is a dictionary with one entry keyed sith "und". That one entry is an array with one element, and that one array element is a dictionary with key "value" and value "2324".

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine that `JSONRepresentation` is formatting `"{\"und\":[{\"value\":\"2324\"}]"` as the literal string it is, not as a value within a dictionary within an array within a dictionary.  You should make the whole dict-array-dict structure. This will all be easier if you use array and dictionary literals:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = @{
    @"name" : @"customer6",
    @"pass" : @"customer6",
    @"mail" : @"customer6@xy.com",

    @"user_roles" : @"5",

    @"field_login_pin_value" : @{
        @"und":@[
            @{
                @"value" : @"2324"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

You can, of course, coalesce the pin_value value to a single line, this is just for clarity.